'intent.getParcelableExtra' type mismatch, deprecated in Java
I'm trying to make a simple apartment rental app for a school project, but I have two problems that have stumped me. Here is the code for the DetailActivity.kt file:
package com.example.project.ui.screens

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.project.data.Apartment
import com.example.project.databinding.ActivityDetailBinding

class DetailActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding:ActivityDetailBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val apartment: Apartment? = intent.getParcelableExtra("APARTMENT")

        apartment?.let {

            binding.textViewName.text = it.apartmentName
            binding.textViewLocation.text= it.apartmentLocation
            binding.textViewPrice.text = "$${it.apartmentPrice}"
            binding.textViewDescription.text = it.apartmentDescription
            Glide.with(this).load(it.apartmentImageUrl).into(binding.textViewImage)
        }
    }

}

I get the errors:
Type mismatch: inferred type is Parcelable? but Apartment? was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is Parcelable! but Apartment? was expected
When I tried changing type of 'Apartment?' to 'Parcelable?', like so:
val apartment: Parcelable? = intent.getParcelableExtra("APARTMENT")

        apartment?.let {

            binding.textViewName.text = it.apartmentName
            binding.textViewLocation.text= it.apartmentLocation
            binding.textViewPrice.text = "$${it.apartmentPrice}"
            binding.textViewDescription.text = it.apartmentDescription
            Glide.with(this).load(it.apartmentImageUrl).into(binding.textViewImage)
        }

This results in getParcelableExtra becoming deprecated (crossed out in Android Studio) and all the values apartmentName, apartmentLocation, apartmentPrice, apartmentDescription and apartmentImageUrl becoming unresolved references.
Also, 'with' in 'Glide.with(this)' becomes crossed out saying 'with(Activity): RequestManager' is deprecated'.
How do I fix all of these issues to make the code function properly? Also, if there are any subsitutes I can use for some of the lines of code, that would be a big help. Thanks.
